# How can I add "Fractions" to input area with JavaScript calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a fraction calculator. Being fairly new to javascript I am running into a few problems. I would like it to be accessible on mobile as well, that being the case I need to have input buttons available. I know what I am trying to do I just don't know how I need to do it.

When a button is pressed I would like to create a new div with the frac class with the corresponding elements and classes, as well as insert the pressed number into that part of the frac div. When an operator button is pressed I would like it to push the fraction that is already there over and display the operator and repeats the process for each fraction, I was thinking of using display:flex so they will add one after another.

How should I go about making that happen? Thank you!

```css
:root {
    --box-size: 35px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #242424;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.input-area {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-area > * {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* FRACTION */

.frac {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.number {
    height: var(--box-size);
    width: var(--box-size);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: var(--box-size);
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.divider {
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.add {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* NumPads */

.button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #ececec;
}

.num-pads {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.num-pads > *,.numerator-num-pad, .denominator-num-pad {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fractions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="input-area">
        <div class="frac">
            <div class="number whole-number">2</div>
            <div class="frac-numbers">
                <div class="number numerator">3</div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="number denominator">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add">+</div>
        <div class="frac">
            <div class="number whole-number">5</div>
            <div class="frac-numbers">
                <div class="number numerator">1</div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="number denominator">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add">+</div>
        <div class="frac">
            <div class="frac-numbers">
                <div class="number numerator">7</div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="number denominator">16</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="num-pads">
        <div class="whole-num-pad">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="frac-parts">
            <div class="numerator-num-pad">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="denominator-num-pad">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: @Rylee I wouldn't be opposed to it, I have touched into it a little bit, but if that would help with my solution then I would be willing to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple example below which will allow the user to click on a fraction and then adjust each part of the selected fraction.

Note: I've used `jQuery` so if you don't have that currently, I'd suggest adding a reference to it.

The script works by listening for `click` events on the numpad. It will check the buttons value to determine what needs to happen (Clear, Remove last character, Add character).

I've added in operator buttons that will append an operator field and a new fraction. The new fraction can then be selected and updated the same way.

```js
$(document)
  .on("click", ".frac", function(){
    // remove "active" class from all .frac
    $(".frac").removeClass("active");
    
    // add "active" class to this .frac
    $(this).addClass("active");
  })
  .on("click", ".whole-num-pad .button", function(){
    // whole number button pressed
    var btnValue    = $(this).val(),
        $target     = $(".frac.active .whole-number"), // get the current active frac
        targetValue = $target.text(); // get the current value of the active frac
    
    if(btnValue === "C"){
      $target.text(""); // clear target
      return;
    }
    
    if(btnValue === "<"){
      // remove the last character from the current value
      $target.text(targetValue.substr(0, targetValue.length - 1));
      return;
    }
    
    // add btnValue to targetValue
    // making sure we pass at least 1 as a string so that JS doesn't attempt to "add"
    $target.text(targetValue + btnValue.toString());
  })
  .on("click", ".numerator-num-pad .button", function(){
    // numerator button pressed
    var btnValue    = $(this).val(),
        $target     = $(".frac.active .numerator"), // get the current active frac
        targetValue = $target.text(); // get the current value of the active frac
    
    if(btnValue === "C"){
      $target.text(""); // clear target
      return;
    }
    
    if(btnValue === "<"){
      // remove the last character from the current value
      $target.text(targetValue.substr(0, targetValue.length - 1));
      return;
    }
    
    // add btnValue to targetValue
    // making sure we pass at least 1 as a string so that JS doesn't attempt to "add"
    $target.text(targetValue + btnValue.toString());
  })
  .on("click", ".denominator-num-pad .button", function(){
    // denominator button pressed
    var btnValue    = $(this).val(),
        $target     = $(".frac.active .denominator"), // get the current active frac
        targetValue = $target.text(); // get the current value of the active frac
    
    if(btnValue === "C"){
      $target.text(""); // clear target
      return;
    }
    
    if(btnValue === "<"){
      // remove the last character from the current value
      $target.text(targetValue.substr(0, targetValue.length - 1));
      return;
    }
    
    // add btnValue to targetValue
    // making sure we pass at least 1 as a string so that JS doesn't attempt to "add"
    $target.text(targetValue + btnValue.toString());
  })
  .on("click", ".operator-button", function(){
    var operator = $(this).val();
    
    switch(operator){
      case "+":
        $(".input-area").append('<div class="add">+</div>');
        break;
      case "-":
        $(".input-area").append('<div class="subtract">-</div>');
        break;
      case "x":
        $(".input-area").append('<div class="multiply">x</div>');
        break;
    }
    
    $(".input-area").append('<div class="frac">\
            <div class="number whole-number"></div>\
            <div class="frac-numbers">\
                <div class="number numerator"></div>\
                <div class="divider"></div>\
                <div class="number denominator"></div>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
  });
```

```css
:root {
    --box-size: 35px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #242424;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.input-area {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
}

.input-area > * {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* FRACTION */

.frac {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.frac.active {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.number {
    height: var(--box-size);
    width: var(--box-size);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: var(--box-size);
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.divider {
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.add,
.subtract,
.multiply {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* NumPads */

.button,
.operator-button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #ececec;
}

.num-pads {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.num-pads > *,.numerator-num-pad, .denominator-num-pad {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fractions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="input-area">
        <div class="frac">
            <div class="number whole-number">2</div>
            <div class="frac-numbers">
                <div class="number numerator">3</div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="number denominator">8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add">+</div>
        <div class="frac">
            <div class="number whole-number">5</div>
            <div class="frac-numbers">
                <div class="number numerator">1</div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="number denominator">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add">+</div>
        <div class="frac">
            <div class="number whole-number"></div>
            <div class="frac-numbers">
                <div class="number numerator">7</div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="number denominator">16</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="operator-buttons">
      <input type="button" class="operator-button" value="+" />
      <input type="button" class="operator-button" value="-" />
      <input type="button" class="operator-button" value="x" />
    </div>

    <div class="num-pads">
        <div class="whole-num-pad">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="frac-parts">
            <div class="numerator-num-pad">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="denominator-num-pad">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0"></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="<"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can be improved by having functions to handle the `click` events - but I thought I'd provide something that you can at least use as a start